# what is the difference between css font size using em and percentage?

Tags: css, font-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Font size in CSS - % or em?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132685/font-size-in-css-or-em)

well i was trying to understand the different sizing options in css and i got lost between ems and percentage.
they seems to be the same i mean 1em = 150% and 1.5em = 150%.
and they do cascade too from parent elements.
am i missing something?

Comment: i have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132685/font-size-in-css-or-em but really it dont explain the different and i have the read the http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss too. its not a duplicate

Comment: EM has always been a unit of measurement in the field of typography, so thats one of the Reasons why its still exists. Another Reason, while you are right, it works exactly as % does, from a typographycal Point of view its Easier to work with.

Comment: @Hannes: so basically an em is like a %/100 ? i got confused really, because people recomment using a 62.5% on the body and then ems elseswhere , but if they are the same so i can use % on the body and % on other elements. but there should be a reason why they are recommending this.

Comment: I think its a matter of Personal Taste, i prefer to Use EM for Typography and % for Elements for example. In the Past it was also a matter with Page-Zoom, but nowadays most Browser can do that perfectly fine without to relay on em based Typography

Comment: @Hannes: so 100% = 1em in all cases?,no difference at all?

Comment: @Karim in regards to styling Behavior? None then I'm aware of, but I'm not a CSS Guru so I would give you a 95% sure on that ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think this site may help with your question

http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: 404 Not Found. Perfect example why SO answers should not defer to external links and should always provide a context.