# CSS: 100% font size - 100% of what?

Tags: css, font-size

There are [many](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss) [articles](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props) and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132685/font-size-in-css-or-em) about [percentage-sized vs other-sized](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) fonts. However, I can not find out WHAT the reference of the percent-value is supposed to be. I understand this is 'the same size in all browsers'. I also read this, for instance:

> Percent (%): The percent unit is much like the “em” unit, save for a few fundamental differences. First and foremost, the current font-size is equal to 100% (i.e. 12pt = 100%). While using the percent unit, your text remains fully scalable for mobile devices and for accessibility.

Source: http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

But if you say "ie 12 pt = 100%", then it means you first have to define `font-size: 12pt`. Is that how it works? You first define a size in an absolute measure, and then refer to this as '100%'? Does not make a lot of sense, as many samples say it is useful to put:

```
body {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

So by doing this, *WHAT* is the font size relative to? I notice that the size I see on my screen differs for every font. Arial looks way bigger than Times New Roman, for instance. Also, if I would just do this, body size = 100%, would *that* mean that it will be the same on all browsers? Or only if I first define an absolute value?

**UPDATE, SAT JUL 23**

I am getting there, but please bear with me.

So, the % value relates to the default browser font size, if I understand correctly. Well, that is nice but gives me again several other questions:

1. Is this standard size always the same for every browser version, or do they vary between versions?
2. I ! found (see image below) the settings for Google Chrome (never looked at this before!), and I see standard "serif", "sans-serif" and "monospace" settings. But how do I interpret this for other fonts? Say I define `font: 100% Georgia;`, what size will the browser take? Will it look up the standard size for serif, or has the "Georgia" font a standard size for the browser
3. On several websites I [read](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss) things like `Sizing text and line-height in ems, with a percentage specified on the body [..], was shown to provide **accurate, resizable text across all browsers** in common use today`. But from what I am learning now I believe that you should actually choose between either resizable text (using % or em, like what they recommend in this quote), or having 'accurate, consistent font-sizes across browsers' (by using px or pt as a base). Is this correct?

Google Settings:

[image: Google Chrome Settinsg]

This is how I *think* things *could* look like if you do not define the size in absolute values.

[image]

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The browser default which is something like 16pt for Firefox, You can check by going into Firefox options, clicking the Content tab, and checking the font size. You can do the same for other browsers as well.

I personally like to control the default font size of my websites, so in a CSS file that is included in every page I will set the BODY default, like so:

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px
}
```

Now the font-size of all my HTML tags will inherit a font-size of 14px.

Say that I want a all divs to have a font size 10% bigger than body, I simply do:

```
div {
    font-size: 110%
}
```

Now any browser that view my pages will autmoatically make all divs 10% bigger than that of the body, which should be something like 15.4px.

If I want the font-size of all div's to be 10% smaller, I do:

```
div {
    font-size: 90%
}
```

This will make all divs have a font-size of 12.6px.

Also you should know that since font-size is inherited, that each nested div will decrease in font size by 10%, so:

```
<div>Outer DIV.
    <div>Inner DIV</div>
</div>
```

The inner div will have a font-size of 11.34px (90% of 12.6px), which may not have been intended.

This can help in the explanation:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#value-def-percentage

Comment: Thanks! This makes it a lot clearer. But I'm still wondering about articles claiming 'accuracy' or 'consistency' when using %. This appears to be quite WRONG if I interpret your answer correctly. I have updated the question with some additional questions...

Comment: The answer to the question asked (100% of what?) is incorrect, there are several inaccuracies (not all elements inherit font size), and there are notes and opinions on issues that were not asked about.

Comment: Pixel density really has to be taken into account.  Something that's 100% of the page on a 4K phone will think it has thousands of pixels of horizontal and vertical resolution.  For Flash content with NO_SCALE, e.g. web-apps, etc., the controls will be tiny, especially menus, for example on an LG G3.  This is equally true for some HTML content that's sized to pixels.  One way or another, pixel density (pixels per inch), must be taken into account, either through the use of completely relative units or JavaScript-based dynamic resizing.

Comment: Confirmed that modern browsers still use 12pt/16px@96ppi as the default. On a related note, you can use "rem" instead of "em" to always scale a specific element relative to the root (html element, or browser default). Can be useful with a complex hierarchy of relatively-sized elements.

Comment: It's better to set your `font-size` using relative units such as `em`, `rem`, or `%`. Using `px` will override the browser's default font size! Many users specify a custom font size to make reading text easier.

Comment: Just for note: `font-size:100%` keep you away headaches, So you don`t need to specify font size for every device your web/app to work!  Even size your elements  based on em will make a web UI look great.

Answer (score 17):

My understanding is that when the font is set as follows

```
body {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

the browser will render the font as per the user settings for that browser.

The spec says that % is rendered

> relative to parent element's font size

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#font-size

In this case, I take that to mean what the browser is set to.

Comment: actually the parent of `body` is `html`. so `body { font-size: 100%; }` will be 100% of the `html`’s font size, not the browser default. Usually these are one in the same, though, so you are effectively correct. But sometimes you'll see an `html { font-size: ??? }` rule.

Answer (score 10):

A percentage in the value of the `font-size` property is relative to **the parent element’s font size**. CSS 2.1 says this obscurely and confusingly (referring to “inherited font size”), but CSS3 Text [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-prop) it very clearly.

The parent of the `body` element is the root element, i.e. the `html` element. Unless set in a style sheet, the font size of the root element is implementation-dependent. It typically depends on user settings.

Setting `font-size: 100%` is pointless in many cases, as an element inherits its parent’s font size (leading to the same result), if no style sheet sets its own font size. However, it can be useful to override settings in other style sheets (including browser default style sheets).

For example, an `input` element typically has a setting in browser style sheet, making its default font size smaller than that of copy text. If you wish to make the font size the same, you can set

input { font-size: 100% }

For the `body` element, the logically redundant setting `font-size: 100%` is used fairly often, as it is believed to help against some browser bugs (in browsers that probably have lost their significance now).

Comment: The one instance where `font-size:100%` could serve a purpose is in Quirks mode, where font sizes are not inherited into tables. With this style, tables do get the parent font size. Of course, nobody in their right mind uses Quirks mode any more...

Answer (score 6):

Sorry if I'm late to the party, but in your edit you make a remark about `font: 100% Georgia`, which the other answers haven't responded to.

There is a difference between `font: 100% Georgia` and `font-size:100%; font-family:'Georgia'`. If that was all the shorthand method did, the font-size part would be meaningless. But it also sets a lot of properties to their default values: the line height becomes `normal` (or around 1.2), ditto for the style (non-italic) and weight (non-bold).

That's all. The other answers already mentioned everything else there was to mention.

Answer (score 5):

It's relative to default browser font-size unless you override it with a value in pt or px.

Comment: So this would vary if every browser?

Comment: Yes, every browser has it's own default settings, including font-size. That's why you usually have to use css reset.

Comment: This is incorrect. It is the percentage of the parent element. You might be experiencing the percentage of the default font-size because your parent element inherited the default font-size.

Comment: @Zectbumo Right, not quite precise. But the question mentions `body`, not an arbitrarily nested element, so the answer is correct with a small asterisk :)

Comment: :-/ except that it is nested because the parent of <body> is <html>

Answer (score 4):

According to **ALL THE SPECS DATING BACK TO 1996**, percentage values on `font-size` refer to the parent element's *(computed)* font-size.

```
<style>
div {
  font-size: 16px;
}
span {
  font-size: 75%;
}
</style>
<div><span>this font size is 12px!</span></div>
```

It's that easy.

What if the `div` declares a relative font-size, like `em`s, or even worse, another percentage?? See *“computed”* above. Whatever absolute unit the relative unit converts to.

The only question that remains is what happens when you use a percentage value on the root element, which has no parent:

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; /* 62.5% of what? */
}
```

In that case, see [the “duplicate”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503196/what-does-font-size-100-on-the-html-element-do) of this question. TLDR: percentages on the root element refer to the browser default font size, which might be different per user.

References:

- [CSS 1 spec (1996)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#font-size)
- [CSS 2.1 spec (2011)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-size)
- [CSS Fonts Level 3 spec (2013)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#percentage-size-value)
- [CSS Fonts Level 3 editor’s draft (2017)](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#length-percentage-size-value)

Answer (score 3):

As you showed convincingly, the `font-size: 100%;` will not render the same in all browsers. However, you will set your font face in your CSS file, so this will be the same (or a fallback) in all browsers.

I believe `font-size: 100%;` can be very useful when combining it with `em`-based design. As [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/power-em-units-css/) shows, this will create a very flexible website.

When is this useful? When your site needs to adapt to the visitors' wishes. Take for example an elderly man that puts his default font-size at 24 px. Or someone with a small screen with a large resolution that increases his default font-size because he otherwise has to squint. Most sites would break, but em-based sites are able to cope with these situations.

Answer (score 1):

Relative to the default size defined to that font.

If someone opens your page on a web browser, there's a default font and font size it uses.

Answer (score 0):

As to my understanding it help your content adjust with different values of font family and font sizes.Thus making your content scalable. As to the issue of inhering font size we can always override by giving a specific font size for the element.