# How to make text take full width of it's container?

Tags: css

Say the div have 300px of width, how would I set the font-size of the text, so that it would always take 100% of the width, considering the text is never the same length (the text is some dynamic titles generated by php). Smaller text would have to have a font a lot smaller than the bigger text, etc

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803016/css-100-font-size-100-of-what... And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718840/make-text-height-100-of-div. Hope those post help you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force single line of text in element to fill width with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199057/force-single-line-of-text-in-element-to-fill-width-with-css)

Answer (score 47):

this did the trick for me

```
div {
  text-align: justify;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However using that trick I had to force the height of my element to prevent it for adding a new empty line.

I took that answer from [Force single line of text in element to fill width with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199057/css-force-single-line-of-text-in-element-to-fill-width)

Also have look here for explanations: http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/css/css-one-line-justify.html

Comment: Originally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199057/force-single-line-of-text-in-element-to-fill-width-with-css

Comment: I removed `content: "";` and it still works while not adding new line.

Comment: i removed the second style (div:after) and it works. it is the same effect like deleting (content: "";)

Answer (score 19):

The solution provided by @svassr combined with `font-size: *vw` gave me the desired result. So:

```
div {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 4.3vw;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

the `vw` stands for `viewport width`, in this example 4.3% of the width of the viewport. Play around with that to get your text fit on one line. Combined with  @svassr's solution this worked like a charm for me!

Comment: Thanks for that `vw`-hint. Just had to add `text-justify: inter-character;` to my styles, to have all chars across the full container width.

Answer (score 13):

What you ask can probably not be done. `text-align:justify` will make paragraph text extend to the right side, but you cannot adjust the size of a header so its 100% of the width.

Edit: Well, actually, a JS library exist that seems to do this. http://fittextjs.com. Still, no pure-CSS solution is available.

Answer (score 5):

I've created a web component for this:
https://github.com/pomber/full-width-text

Check the demo here:
https://pomber.github.io/full-width-text/

The usage is like this:

```
<full-width-text>Lorem Ipsum</full-width-text>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've prepared simple scale function using css transform instead of font-size.

Blog post:
https://blog.polarbits.co/2017/03/07/full-width-css-js-scalable-header/

The code:

```
function scaleHeader() {
  var scalable = document.querySelectorAll('.scale--js');
  var margin = 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < scalable.length; i++) {
    var scalableContainer = scalable[i].parentNode;
    scalable[i].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
    var scalableContainerWidth = scalableContainer.offsetWidth - margin;
    var scalableWidth = scalable[i].offsetWidth;
    scalable[i].style.transform = 'scale(' + scalableContainerWidth / scalableWidth + ')';
    scalableContainer.style.height = scalable[i].getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
  }
}
```

Working demo:
https://codepen.io/maciejkorsan/pen/BWLryj

Comment: Again, OP is looking for a css solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is away to do it without the extra line problem: just add ***margin-bottom*** to the div

(I'm using SCSS)

```
div {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: -1em !important;

    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```