# Evenly space out text inside a TextView

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way to make a given text fill up the entire `TextView` `width` no matter on the length of the text by stretching the spaces between characters, similar to how word does so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are pretty limited with TextView.

SUGGESTION: Try WebView (or equivalent), and you might be able to do something like this:

[Force single line of text in element to fill width with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26497966/3135317)

```
div {
  text-align: justify;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on width of your `TextView`, calculate new letter spacing then use `TextView.setLetterSpacing(float letterSpacing)`.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing(float) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically set spacing to fit the entire width?

Comment: @Eddie In my best knowledge, there is no automatic method like that!

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but for anyone else wondering how to do this with a textview:

## Use this function

**The text must also be alligned to the center and the max lines must be set to 1**

```
    public static double even_text_spacing(TextView textView){
        float even_letter_spacing_px = textView.getWidth()/(textView.getText().toString().length()+2);
        float even_letter_spacing_ems = even_letter_spacing_px/textView.getTextSize();

        return even_letter_spacing_ems;
    }
```

This function uses the width of the textview and the amount of letters to calculate even letter spacing in ems.

### Usage

```
textView.setLetterSpacing((float) even_text_spacing(textView));
```

After applying this to your textView, remember to align the text to the center of the view and set the line spacing to 1.

#### to center and set max lines programatically:

```
textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
textView.setMaxLines(1);
```

#### to center and set max lines in XML:

```
android:textAlignment="center"
android:maxLines="1"
```