# What does font-size: 100% on the html element do?

Tags: html, css

I am in the process to start a new project. I am asking myself: Why should I add `font-size: 100%` on the `html` element when I am using the `em` unit anyway?

What does this `100%` to - 100% compared to what?

Comment: Compared to the inherited font size, same as em (for the root element, that's the default text size)

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803016/css-100-font-size-100-of-what?rq=1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many types of declaring the font-size as the same value for the browser.

1. `font-size: 1em;`
2. `font-size: 100%;`
3. `font-size: 16px; // this is default`

This way, you can get the default font-size. But note that 16 px will alter the font-size, however `em` and `%` will depend on the font-size used in the body tag.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/5Wkus/

So you'll see, em depends totally on the font-declared in `body`. Or you can say, it runs from child to parent. It keeps looking for the font-size change in the nearest parent. Which in most cases directs the code to the body element or the user agent default stylesheet.

Comment: The last paragraph is incorrect. What you're seeing is that the font size of `body` is unaffected because you're not actually changing the font size of `html`. It does not cause `html` to take on the font size of `body`.

Answer (score 5):

font size 100% on html is equal to browsers default font size, which can be 14px or 16px.