# React Native set font size to fill parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, font-size

Is there a way to  set fontSize of a text to occupy all disponible space ?

e.g. I have a screen with multiple elements and I would like to have a text in the orange element and tell the text to occupy all the available space (in orange).

[image: screen with 3 spaces with different flex propery]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best answer, but i think you can do it using the React Native `Dimensions` API.

Check out the example that i created in snack.expo.io:

https://snack.expo.io/@luaneduardo/19a766

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `font-size: 100%`

**BUT!** This `100%` based on the parent element `font-size`, not on the current element `size`.

So if you want your font fills full of the current element, you can make an approach:

```
<div style={{fontSize: `800px`}}>
  <div style={{height: `800px`, fontSize: `100%`}}>
    Some Text
  </div>
</div>
```

And you can make it more programmatically, based on your demand.

---

Refer: Related QA: [CSS: 100% font size - 100% of what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803016/css-100-font-size-100-of-what)