# Why not use percentage for font-size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, percentage, font-size

Basically I'm asking the same question as raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323792/using-percent-for-font-size), but it didn't get a clear and straightaway answer. So. **Why not use percentage for font-size**/line-height?

As far as I'm aware of at the moment:

1. it adjusts the font size according to its parent. If not set explicitly, will search up for reference until it finally reaches the `html` tag.
2. And if the font-size of a parent div is set to percentage, its children paragraphs will have to take that into account as well (times that).

Workaround:

So my solution is to set percentage font-sizes only for content tags like `h1` and `p`, while keeping `div` tags clean without them. In which case, if I control the base font-size of `html` on resize, I'll have control over all the fonts.

Benefit:

And the difference between this and `em` would be browser compatibility (I'm not sure about this one, but I guess percentage should have a better shot than `em` s).

So my questions are:

1. **How's its compatibility, if anyone had tried this before and gave up?**
2. **Why is this not not common practice and what have I failed to take into account?**

Comment: While I haven't checked myself, setting font size to a percentage would cause the text to be redrawn each time.  While the browser is already doing the refresh, it maybe of minimal impact.  I would also image on a mobile platform, the smaller screen might have an impact.

Comment: Who says not to use percentages for font sizes? YUI 2 does it.

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qY6qJ/

Comment: First of all, you have to define what is compatibility to you? What are the targeted browsers? There is no universal rule saying which one is better, it depends on where you use it, how you use it. To deal with different browsers on different devices, it is unlikely that you can apply one rule that fits all, just like the html protocol is never unified on all (or at least the major) browsers. My suggestion is, use one that fits your needs most, then tweak a little on the part that is incompatible (to you) on some browsers.

Comment: Good point, I used PX, EM and REM in the past but since the last 3 projects I use % - no problems (mobile or dekstop) and less stress for me. The size is inherited - but yeah you know it! And it's logical. So you can deal with that - see no problem here. For line-height I use unitless values - as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

General best practice, when taking mobile devices into consideration, is to use ems. They tend to be represented better for mobile, and there are several articles you can Google to find references of this.

I have only recently switched from px to ems, and now my plan is to switch to rem for my font size. Rem will be calculated from the html root font size, whereas ems can be tricky when nested as they calculate from their parent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using rems right now, but chrome on pc is not displaying it right, causing font-size to not shrink enough when zoomed down (surprisingly IE 9 is fine). Not to mention it's not supported in earlier browsers. So I'm asking about compatibility of all the methods, compared to percentage, which seemingly should be fine for all.

Answer (score 0):

Using percentages for font-sizing is perfectly fine. However, i think that the reason why they are not as widely implemented on the web is because they were never designed to be used for typographic use, like the EM, PX, PT and as of recently REM units.

Compatibility really depends on your project requirements. I think the best workaround for you would be to set a percentage to the html root or the body element, like so:

```
html {
font-size: 62.5%; /* Sets up the Base 10 stuff */
}
```

As long as the base element is set using a percentage value you can then use whichever unit you like for font sizing and you will still retain the benefits of relevant font-sizing, which from what i understand is what you are after.

My personal recommendation would be to use REM's instead. They are similar to EM's but instead of cascading down, they would always be relevant to the root element. And if that's set in a relative unit(percentage), it will always refer to that first. Browser support is decent(not supported in IE9<) but you can always provide PX based solutions for legacy browsers, which is what makes this technique so efficient. To set it up, it would look something like  this:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
body { font-size: 14px; font-size: 1.4rem; } /* =14px */
h1   { font-size: 24px; font-size: 2.4rem; } /* =24px */
```

I hope this helps. Essentially, using percentages everywhere is not really needed when you can just specify a percent to the  root element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the future of responsive design lies in this technique of applying a percentage-based font size on the body tag, as it relates to truly proportional grid systems and modular scale typography.

The idea - you set up a global modular scale for the typography once, at the mobile sizing, and apply a 100% font-size on the body. This includes ems (or rems) for your headers, but not your paragraph (p). Leave your p's alone, as they'll inherit their size from the body.

Additionally, your grid system and media queries (and all other margins and paddings) should also be entirely ems / rems, with a percentage-based container width.

Then, as you move up in break points, use media queries to target and increase just the body's font-size percentage, while adjusting your container's percentage width.

With this approach, you only have to set font-sizes once, rather than adjusting all your headers and p's at every break.

Plus, if you ever need to modify the font sizes because the client says their too big, just decrease the body's font-size % and call it a day.

For setting up modular scale typography, use a tool like [Grid Lover](http://www.gridlover.net/) as the jump off. It's great.

For better insight into this concept, Trent Walton [did a nice post a while back](http://trentwalton.com/2012/06/19/fluid-type/).