# % is not working sometime in position CSS

Tags: css, css-position

I am applying position(in %) to some div but it is not working. Here is the code.

```
#transitions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 70%;
  display: block;
}
```

But when i apply:

```
  #transitions {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 70em;
    display: block;
  }
```

it is working for me.

Is there any diffrence b/w % or em ?

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132685/font-size-in-css-or-em

Comment: However, you can still have a look at : http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: What is the css of the #transitions container ?

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of difference between `em` and `%`.

`%` represents the percentage size of the element's container. In the following example, the `<div>` will be 70% of the width of the page.

```
<body>
    <div>A div</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
div { width: 70%; }
```

`em` represents the size of a capital 'M' based on the current `font-size`. With the following CSS instead, the `<div>` will be the size of 70 'M' characters.

```
div { width: 70em; }
```

Your example will position the `#transitions` element's left hand-side at 70% of the way through it's container. OR 70 'M' characters away from the left hand side of it's container.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate % vs em then it is likely to be this 170% = 32px = 2 em in font sizes like this you could calculate it 1 em = 16px and 100px = 531.25 %