# What is the difference between % and em?

Tags: css

What is the difference between % and em length values? If containing elements'font-size is 10px, 1em = 10px and so is 100% = 10px. None of the answers in Stackoverflow answers this particular question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the difference between pixels and percentage in css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226439/what-is-the-difference-between-pixels-and-percentage-in-css)

Comment: read this link http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: my question is between em and %, not between em and px.

Comment: the link does not explain the difference between em and % completely.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132685/font-size-in-css-or-em

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between px, em and ex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385829/what-is-the-difference-between-px-em-and-ex)

Comment: this question has been answered multiple times already, search before asking any question. If already answered questions doesn't help then ask question with details like what you are asking apart from other questions ? -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: please give link of definitive answer.

Comment: px vs em is different from % vs em.

Answer (score 4):

`em` unit is dependent of `font-size`.
It can be used for fit sizechanged/zoomed texts.

In the snippet below you can see difference:

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.fs');

let fs = 10;
setInterval(() => {
  if (fs > 36) fs = 10;
  list.forEach(el => el.style.fontSize = fs+'pt');
  fs += 1;
}, 100)
```

```css
.em {
  width: 2em;
  background-color: cyan;
}
.perc {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="em fs">2em</div>
<div class="perc fs">10%</div>
```

Comment: % is dependent on what?

Comment: on nearest parent `position:relative/absolute` container size. In my snippet it's `document.body` width

Answer (score 1):

`em` is a relative measure to the current font-size of the element in question. 1em is equal to the current font-size of the element in question.

If you haven't set font size anywhere on the page, then it would be the browser default, which is probably 16px. So by default 1em = 16px. If you were to go and set a font-size of 20px on your body, then 1em = 20px.

`%` however does not depend on any specific property. it's reference changes as you apply it on different properties.

See this example:

```css
section{
  width:100%;
}
div{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.a{
  background-color:red;
}
.b{
  background-color:blue;
  width:2em;
}
.c{
  background-color:green;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
</section>
```

Comment: B=100px, A=?, C=?

Comment: `A=50px`   `B=(2*16=32px)`   `C= 50%of screen size`

Comment: since `100%=full size it can extend`, that is size of it's parent element

Comment: parent element of the `C` is the section which covers the full screen. so if screen width is 800px then width of `C` will be 400px

Comment: if section is 50% then B=(2*8=16px)?

Comment: because B is expressed in `em`. its reference is the font-size which is 16 px by default.

Comment: so in short `2em` is twice of it's font size but `200%` is twice of it's parent's size